# Would knowing the file names of password protected ZIP/RAR assist in cracking?

Tags: zip, password-recovery, rar

So I have a couple of password protected rars and zips (don't worry, this is for educational reasons only). I know the exact names of the files in those rars and zips. Dictionary attacking the files didn't seem to help, so I was wondering if the names of those files can be of any help in terms of cracking.

Comment: Only if they used one or more of the file names as the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely not. The encryption key is independent of the filename.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response...that was my initial thought but we couldn't find any other hints to crack these what were supposed to be crackable archives.

Comment: Did you try obvious passwords? E.g. 'secret' 'pasword' and 'password'? (The one with a single s in pasword was actually used for a rar which I recently received.)

Comment: @Hennes yup! we've tried simple letter only passwords but we will figure out another way to get through this. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try battery horse staple? Just in case your prof actually has humour? (See XKCD http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/password_strength.png)

Comment: The ZIP format at one time was susceptible to known-plaintext attacks, and knowing the file names in this case might have helped (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack#Present_day) for more).

Comment: @Hennes and Karan -> I will look into those. Sorry about the late response, and thank you!

Comment: @Karan That would be true, except that encrypted ZIP files don't actually encrypt the filenames, only the contents.  Not sure whether that applies to RAR files or not, though.

Comment: @Jules: So what's your point? Read the wiki link. Knowing the file name *might* help you reconstruct part of it, or locate a copy elsewhere or something. As for RAR, it has an option to encrypt file names in addition to contents.